# Orleans silo can't dynamically load grains from assemblies unless I load them first

Tags: c#, .net, orleans

I'm trying to modify the HelloWorld sample to be able to load the grains/interfaces dynamically without being explicit dependencies of the SiloHost.
However I keep getting errors, either "Orleans.Runtime.OrleansConfigurationException: None of the assemblies added to ApplicationPartManager contain generated code. Ensure that code generation has been executed for grain interface and class assemblies.", or if I try to add ".WithCodeGeneration", I get FileNotFound errors trying to load the DLLs.

So I added a line of code at the beginning of the Silo's main function that explicitly loaded the DLLs in question, and bingo, everything worked just fine - and yes, the grain could successfully be instantiated and called.
I modified it to be

```
 foreach (var fn in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(appDomainBase, "*.dll"))
     System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(fn);
```

And it still worked just fine. Interestingly when I tried to use "LoadFile" it didn't work.

So is there any harm in leaving this here, and why should it be needed anyway?

Comment: Which .NET runtime are you using, .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: .NET core (pad pad)

Comment: I'm unsure of the best solution, but I believe LoadFrom will fail to correctly load assemblies in many cases (eg, issues with binding redirects) on .NET Core especially. See https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/47 and https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/ and https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/25/netcore-plugins/

Comment: Orleans requires knowledge of all grains/grain interfaces/serializers up-front. The way you provide those is through the ApplicationPartManager.

Comment: I originally explicitly added `.ConfigureApplicationParts(parts => parts.AddFromApplicationBaseDirectory())` even though the documentation suggests this is the default behaviour, but this didn't work. With the lines I mentioned above, I don't need this, it automatically loads them correctly.

Comment: I think that's a deficiency on our end: that only works for .NET Framework, since Assembly.Load doesn't work on .NET Core unless the assembly is statically referenced by the application. I don't know of a simple way to make it work correctly, though, given the aforementioned binding issues. Here's the line which is being called and throwing that FileNotFound exception: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/bdaf800326b90c5e0950be6b0a8568add56f3b2c/src/Orleans.Core/AssemblyLoader/AssemblyLoader.cs#L523

If you can improve the experience there, please submit a PR

Comment: I think just changing it to "LoadFrom" is enough though?

Comment: Also, maybe this should be a separate question, but how feasible would it be to support a model where new grains are added dynamically at runtime? I.e. could you deploy new grain assemblies without actually stopping and starting any existing running silo hosts?

Comment: Perhaps we could try Load and drop back to LoadFrom in case we encounter that specific exception. Do you think you could submit a PR?

SO is telling me to avoid having a discussion here. Perhaps a GitHub issue or some words in Gitter chat (https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans) would be more appropriate.